# Wine 1.7.9 and Mono package

Tags: nvidia, wine, games, steam, mono

One day I installed wine 1.7.8 with mono and any game (also steam games) were working great. Few days ago my Linux broke completely so I had to reinstall it, then I updated nvidia drivers and wine like this:

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

Then I released that the new version (1.7.9) installed automatically but without mono package anymore. Until now all the wine games can't run due to fact it cannot find my graphic card drivers.

What can I do in this case? I'm a ubuntu noob btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install  it manually:

```
sudo apt-get install wine-mono
```

or:

```
sudo apt-get install wine-mono4.5.2
```

The second option is the latest mono, which I'm not sure is in the official repositories. The first one should install the latest  mono version for wine available on the official PPA.