# wine doesn't find gecko or mono packages

Tags: 14.04, wine, mono

This is discussed already here: [mono package for wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/577311/mono-package-for-wine) and the ideas there seems to help some people. But I have not enough reputation to comment there.

I have installed wine1.7 and all the recommended packages from ppa and still wine complains about missing gecko and mono packages.

I have two systems, both 14.04 with latest updates. Both have installed:

```
wine1.7 1:1.7.50-0ubuntu1
wine1.7-amd64 1:1.7.50-0ubuntu1
wine1.7-i386:i386 1:1.7.50-0ubuntu1
wine-gecko2.34 2.34-0ubuntu1~ppa1
wine-gecko2.34:i386 2.34-0ubuntu1~ppa1
wine-mono4.5.4 4.5.4-0ubuntu1~ppa1
```

One system complains only about missing gecko package but the other complains about both packages.

What should I do now? I know I can let wine to download the packages but I'm more interested in how can one get the ppa packages install properly.

--

Timo